# Firefox: no focus on input

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, input, focus

I tried a lot of things but nothing works for me.

I try to create a tab-menu. If u double click on one tab, an input-field should popup and u can enter a new name for the tab.

It works on Chrome, Safari and Opera but Firefox cant get focus on my input.

I have to hold my mousebutton down to get focus and enter something into the input-field.

Hope somebody can help me.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Can you post that code sample (CSS, HTML, JS) on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: its working fine on my firefox...

Comment: any specific future question regarding browsers, please mention the browser version as well in your question

Comment: it's working fine on my firefox :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the input is inside a link. I changed it to be a  and it worked quite well  and I could type normally.

Comment: This solves the problem. I changed the link to a div and it works fine.. Thanks!